# Angular JS inspect elements in directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a rather simple select box in angular JS. I am trying to add a class to toggle/hide the individual elements. I have tried in various ways and I am simply not getting something about angular js.

```
<select ng-class="{hide: user.student == false}" class="btn-blockAddress" ng-model="docs.address.type" ng-options="t for t in consts.data.typeOfAddress"></select>
<select ng-class="{hide: user.student != false}" class="btn-blockAddress" ng-model="docs.address.type" ng-options="t for t in consts.data.typeOfAddressForStudent"></select>
```

This is not working for me. It disables one, and not the other select, but then when I change user.student, I expect them to swap, but there is no change.

Should I be defining the behavior of the DOM form some other location? I understood the purpose of angular js was to watch variables for change. I have based my code on similar use in other parts of the codebase.

How do I inspect the value of `user.student` at the point it is evaluated to decide the class?
The javascriptish statements that go in directives are not really javascript - so what is it?

I have found the docs for angular js pretty good to show specific use cases, but I can not find clear API info that I can lookup.

Comment: It should work, can you create a fiddle for this.

Comment: I don't get your issue, it work fine for me : http://jsfiddle.net/DotDotDot/WHus7/1/

Comment: This Google Chrome addon could be very helpful when debugging angular apps. You could try it: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang/ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk?hl=en

Comment: @DotDotDot thanks for that fiddle, it is very helpful. It is good to know the method is roughly correct. I am not sure how I can inspect stuff written in angular js, so I don't know how to find problems. How can I know if `user.student` has a value in the scope/time of evaluation in my snippet? How can I inspect that at all?

Comment: Add `{{user.student}}` to your HTML.

Comment: If you really want to inspect the value of your variable you can try using a function in the ng-class : `{hide: whatIsTheValue()}` then in your controller, your function will do a `console.log($scope.user.student)` then `return !user.student`, everytime the ng-class will try to access it, it will log the value in the console so you can inspect (or `{{user.student}}` in the HTML like in my fiddle )

Comment: Thanks for all the clues - I got there in the end. I was of course watching the wrong variable.

Comment: Consider deleting this question then.

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin for the dev tools called [Batarang](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang/ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk?hl=en) that is life saving. Check out [this video](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=6&cad=rja&ved=0CGIQtwIwBQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3Dq-7mhcHXSfM&ei=xmUKUvqMLuiU2AXA9IHgAQ&usg=AFQjCNGei-0z7tcXaKh-ihLquAytHZGEIg&sig2=wC-Db2eAZCuj5kwq9HBWTQ&bvm=bv.50500085,d.b2I) for usage.